# LRU-2 implementation

Tags: algorithm, caching, data-structures, lru

I am trying to implement a **LRU-2** cache with **PriorityQueue** in Java. It seems to me that I can do `poll()` and `add()` in `O(LogN)` time, but for searching in the cache, it would cost me `O(N)` time. Any suggestion about how to implement a **LRU-2** cache with `poll()`, `add()` and `search()` all in `O(LogN)` time? Or it is just impossible to do so?

Comment: I'd have to analyze LRU-2, but most caches are hash tables with auxiliary structures, e.g. a queue that cross-cuts the entries to order them. Many use doubly-linked lists (e.g. LRU) so that all operations are O(1).

Comment: DoubleLinkedList won't work in the case of LRU-2. I am considering a hashtable and RedBlack Tree, so that all operations are in O(log N). But I am still wondering if there exists a better solution.

Comment: You can probably adapt the [O(1) LFU](http://dhruvbird.com/lfu.pdf) approach. P.S. If you can share your end result that would be great, as I'm starting to flush out a [simulator](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine) for my caching library.

Comment: A maxHeap and hashtable will work. All the operations wiil need O(logN) time in worst case. Thank you. I will share when I finish it. Thank you.

Comment: The O(1) LFU method won't work.

Answer (score 0):

After a little struggling, I got a LRU-2 with MaxHeap and HashMap, operations will need O(log N) time at most. Here is code for LRU-2 in Java. The code is also on my [GitHub](https://github.com/YorkShen/LRU2Cache/).

**Node.java**, this is the value in HashMap and MaxHeap

```
package me.york;

class Node<K, V extends Comparable<V>> implements Comparable<Node<K, V>> {
private K key;
private V value;
private int index;
private long lastTime;
private long lastSecondTime;
public static long INIT = -1;

Node(K key, V value) {
    this.key = key;
    this.value = value;
    lastTime = INIT;
    lastSecondTime = INIT;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Node<K, V> o) {
    return (int)(lastSecondTime-o.getLastSecondTime());
}

K getKey() {
    return key;
}

V getValue() {
    return value;
}

int getIndex() {
    return index;
}

void setIndex(int index) {
    this.index = index;
}

long getLastTime() {
    return lastTime;
}

void setLastTime(long lastTime) {
    this.lastTime = lastTime;
}

long getLastSecondTime() {
    return lastSecondTime;
}

void setLastSecondTime(long lastSecondTime) {
    this.lastSecondTime = lastSecondTime;
}
}
```

**MaxHeap.java**, main logic of the LRU-2 algorithm is in this class.

```
package me.york;

class MaxHeap<K, V extends Comparable<V>> {
private Node<K, V>[] heap;
private int currentSize;
private long count;

MaxHeap(int size) {
    count = 0;
    currentSize = 1;
    heap = new Node[size + 1];
}

boolean isFull() {
    return currentSize >= heap.length;
}

Node<K, V> add(Node<K, V> value) {
    Node<K, V> previous = value;
    if (currentSize >= heap.length) {
        previous = removeMax();
    }
    if (value.getLastSecondTime() != Node.INIT) {
        value.setLastSecondTime(value.getLastTime());
    } else {
        value.setLastSecondTime(count);
    }
    value.setLastTime(count++);
    value.setIndex(currentSize);
    heap[currentSize++] = value;
    siftUp(currentSize - 1);
    return previous;
}

Node<K, V> getMax() {
    return heap[0];
}

Node<K, V> removeMax() {
    return remove(0);
}

Node<K, V> reVisited(int index) {
    Node<K, V> node = heap[index];
    remove(node.getIndex());
    add(node);
    return node;
}

Node<K, V> remove(int index) {
    Node<K, V> previous = heap[index];
    heap[index] = heap[--currentSize];
    siftDown(index);
    return previous;
}

private void siftDown(int index) {
    int left = 2 * index;
    int right = 2 * index + 1;
    int largest;
    if (left < currentSize && heap[left].compareTo(heap[index]) > 0)
        largest = left;
    else
        largest = index;
    if (right < currentSize && heap[right].compareTo(heap[largest]) > 0)
        largest = right;
    if (largest != index) {
        Node<K, V> temp = heap[index];
        heap[index] = heap[largest];
        heap[largest] = temp;
        heap[index].setIndex(largest);
        heap[largest].setIndex(index);
        siftDown(largest);
    }
}

private void siftUp(int index) {
    while (index > 1 && heap[index].compareTo(heap[index / 2]) > 0) {
        Node<K, V> temp = heap[index];
        heap[index] = heap[index / 2];
        heap[index / 2] = temp;
        heap[index].setIndex(index / 2);
        heap[index / 2].setIndex(index);
        index = index / 2;
    }
}
}
```

**LRU2Cache.java**, this is the entry for LRU-2 cache algorithm. It simply provides two functions, get() and put().

```
package me.york;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class LRU2Cache<K, V extends Comparable<V>> {
private MaxHeap<K, V> maxHeap;
private Map<K, Node<K, V>> map;

public LRU2Cache(int cacheSize) {
    maxHeap = new MaxHeap<K, V>(cacheSize);
    map = new HashMap<K, Node<K, V>>((int) ((float) cacheSize / 0.75F + 1.0F));
}

public void put(K key, V value) {
    if (key != null && value != null) {
        Node<K, V> previous;
        if ((previous = map.get(key)) != null) {
            maxHeap.remove(previous.getIndex());
        }
        if (maxHeap.isFull())
            map.remove(maxHeap.getMax().getKey());
        previous = new Node<K, V>(key, value);
        map.put(key, previous);
        maxHeap.add(previous);
    }
}

public V get(K key) {
    V value = null;
    if (key != null) {
        Node<K, V> node = map.get(key);
        if (node != null) {
            value = node.getValue();
            maxHeap.reVisited(node.getIndex());
        }
    }
    return value;
}
}
```

Comment: It looks like you forgot to evict from the hashmap.

Comment: Oh, and `compareTo` always returns zero which will invalidate the heap.

Comment: Eviction doesn't appear to use the access times, so my reading is that this is a bounded `SortedMap` that removes the last entry, where the order is oddly defined by the value.

Comment: Thank you for noticing. The max item should be the first item in the array, eg. heap[0]. Thank you.

Comment: I think you could use Java's `TreeMap` instead of your heap where the comparator looks at time 2 if set, else time 1. I am pretty sure that you could make it O(1) using the LFU trick (see my quick hack of one [here](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/blob/4d14d499f82c707b87702b6c026bfdb01d16c393/simulator/src/main/java/com/github/benmanes/caffeine/cache/simulator/policy/linked/FrequentlyUsedPolicy.java)). I can port this into my simulator if you're interested in comparing hit rates.

Comment: I have fixed my comparetTo to use secondLasttime. A treemap and hashmap together will definitely work. As for O(1), I am not sure about that, but I will read the code.

Comment: I played around with writing a version of your code using TreeMap and k-depth using an ArrayDeque per node. The hit rate was lower than regular LRU, so I read the paper. There are some tuning constants that you are missing which seem important to get the full affect.